# You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element, knockout js problem

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I need help about this error. I am trying to change the visibility of div element by choosing options from the drop down list but I am getting this error all the time.

Here is my code

.js file:

```
var viewModel = {
            currentSelect : ko.observable("CostPools")
        };
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

html file:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <h4 class="section-title">Actuals vs Budgeted Amounts for Cost Pools and IT Towers</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <select data-bind="value: currentSelect">
                    <option value="costPools">Show Cost Pools</option>
                    <option value="itTowers">Show IT Towers</option>
                    <option value="showBoth">Show Both</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ko if: currentSelect() === 'costPools' -->
    <div style="width: 98%; height: 300px;" id="cost-pools-chart"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: currentSelect() === 'itTowers' -->
    <div style="width: 98%; height: 300px;" id="it-towers-chart"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: currentSelect() === 'showBoth' -->
    <div style="width: 98%; height: 300px;" id="cost-pools-chart"></div>
    <hr />
    <div style="width: 98%; height: 300px;" id="it-towers-chart"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
```

I need to show those two divs depending on the drop down list. For example if Cost Pools is selected show the Cost Pools div, if IT Towers option is selected show IT Towers div and in the end if Show Both is selected show both divs with hr/.
The problem is that I am not sure what can be the issue here, and that I have never implemented dropdown list before can you help ? thanks you in advance.

The error: Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my code how am I binding to the viewModel and declare a variables.